# Installation of a scoped package resolve in an E404

Tags: node.js, module, npm, npm-install

So I came across this problem when I am trying to install the request-promise module via npm.

It depends on a scoped package named @request/promise-core, and when I try to launch `npm install request-promise` from my project directory it returns me an error 404. This apparently it is a known issue, see: https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/137, but none of the solutions works for me, probably due to a wrong implementation on my side.

What I tried so far:

- configured `npm config set "@request:registry" https://registry.npmjs.org/`, but did not worked. Still returning E404
- tried to manually install the package via github with `npm install https://github.com/request/request-promise` but no joy since it returns error: ENOEN when trying to open the *request-promise-unpack/package.json* file.

Probably I am missing some basic steps when trying to install the module, but I cannot figure out a different way of installing that module.

Any suggestions or alternatives is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed with

`npm install -g npm`

in the terminal and then I could install it:

`npm install --save request-promise`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked! I did not hink of installing npm globally. Does it comes with a downside?